# Rasterize polygons with R

Tags: raster, r, polygon

I have this spatial object:

```
> polys
Simple feature collection with 24 features and 2 fields
geometry type:  POLYGON
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: 4530000 ymin: 3517000 xmax: 4536000 ymax: 3521000
epsg (SRID):    NA
proj4string:    +proj=laea +lat_0=52 +lon_0=10 +x_0=4321000 +y_0=3210000 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs
   Id total                       geometry
1   0     7 POLYGON ((4530000 3517000, ...
2   1     3 POLYGON ((4531000 3517000, ...
3   2     8 POLYGON ((4532000 3517000, ...
```

It is a polygon geometry type. I would like to save it as a raster file but I still can not manage!

I tried to create a raster with `r <- raster(ncols=6, nrows=4)` and then to x <- `rasterize(polys,r,getCover=TRUE,progress="text")` but it can not make it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

try

```
library(sf)
r <- raster(as(polys, "Spatial"), ncols = 6, nrows = 4)
```

which will give a raster with the right extents and projection metadata, and then this should work

```
 rr <- rasterize(as(polys, "Spatial"), r, getCover = TRUE, progress = "text")
```

Consider changing ncols/nrows to get better resolution, or you can set `res` instead to get pixel size/s - and many other options to control the extent and so on.

The problem with your initial attempt is that the the extents of your target raster didn't overlap the polys, compare

```
extent(as(polys, "Spatial"))
```

with

```
extent(raster(ncols = 6, nrows = 4))
```

Finally, if you need better performance or want to work with `sf` objects then check out the `velox` package, it works a bit differently with objects/methods - though, and, it doesn't have `getCover` so ...

Comment: thanks @mdsummer. After the first line I have as rresult: ´Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘raster’ for signature ‘"sf"’ ´

Comment: uh yeah, sorry missed that it's sf already - edited to cast to Spatial - (possibly the newest version of raster does this now)

Comment: @midsumner, what if I already have a grid imported as shp file with readOGR() ? That would help me to rasterize on a grid that I already have!

Comment: Sure, it can be a bit tricky to turn a grid of polygons into an exactly matching raster grid, but happy to help with that, though ask a new question since it's pretty different. You can create any target grid with raster's functions, and if your polygon grid is really a regular one then you only need extent and resolution to describe it.

Comment: When I use your code my polygons remain empty. Only when I set getCover=FALSE, then my desired values are used. Why should one bother with getCover?

Answer (score 1):

Check the output of `r` object:

```
r
## class       : RasterLayer 
## dimensions  : 4, 6, 24  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
## resolution  : 60, 45  (x, y)
## extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
## coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0
```

Is a raster with a coarse resolution and different CRS... It'll don't match with your polygons.

Try something like this to create a base raster:

```
r <- raster(nrows = 100, ncols = 150, xmn = 4530000, xmx = 4536000, ymn = 3517000, ymx = 3521000,
       crs = '+proj=laea +lat_0=52 +lon_0=10 +x_0=4321000 +y_0=3210000 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs')
r
## class       : RasterLayer 
## dimensions  : 100, 150, 15000  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
## resolution  : 40, 40  (x, y)
## extent      : 4530000, 4536000, 3517000, 3521000  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
## coord. ref. : +proj=laea +lat_0=52 +lon_0=10 +x_0=4321000 +y_0=3210000 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs
```