# R: grid of polygons to raster file for Esri?

Tags: raster, r, esri-grid-format

I have the following grid of polygons (cf. at the end of the message). I would like to export it as a raster file that I could open with ArcMap.

I tried to actually add it to a grid that I already have (raster):

```
> grid <- readOGR("W:/FlorentDrafts/Grid24Cells","Grid1km_BalticSea_SAMPLE_24Cells")
OGR data source with driver: ESRI Shapefile 
Source: "W:/FlorentDrafts/Grid24Cells", layer: "Grid1km_BalticSea_SAMPLE_24Cells"
with 24 features
It has 1 fields
Integer64 fields read as strings:  Id 
> grid
class       : SpatialPolygonsDataFrame 
features    : 24 
extent      : 4530000, 4536000, 3517000, 3521000  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=laea +lat_0=52 +lon_0=10 +x_0=4321000 +y_0=3210000 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs 
variables   : 1
names       : Id 
min values  : -1 
max values  :  0
```

But I can not succeed using rasterize. I used the following lines:

```
coordinates(grid)
test_grid <- rasterFromXYZ(coordinates(grid))
rr <- rasterize(as(polys, "Spatial"), test_grid, getCover = TRUE, progress = "text").
```

It is possible to export such a grid of polygons as a ESRI raster file?

**Here is the grid:**

```
polys <-
structure(list(Id = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23), total = c(7, 3, 
8, 5, 2, 1, 2, 6, 4, 9, 8, 11, 2, 10, 1, 3, 4, 3, 2, 5, NA, 1, 
NA, NA), geometry = structure(list(structure(list(structure(c(4530000, 
4530000, 4531000, 4531000, 4530000, 3517000, 3518000, 3518000, 
3517000, 3517000), .Dim = c(5L, 2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", 
"sfg")), structure(list(structure(c(4531000, 4531000, 4532000, 
4532000, 4531000, 3517000, 3518000, 3518000, 3517000, 3517000
), .Dim = c(5L, 2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(
    structure(c(4532000, 4532000, 4533000, 4533000, 4532000, 
    3517000, 3518000, 3518000, 3517000, 3517000), .Dim = c(5L, 
    2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(
    structure(c(4533000, 4533000, 4534000, 4534000, 4533000, 
    3517000, 3518000, 3518000, 3517000, 3517000), .Dim = c(5L, 
    2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(
    structure(c(4534000, 4534000, 4535000, 4535000, 4534000, 
    3517000, 3518000, 3518000, 3517000, 3517000), .Dim = c(5L, 
    2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(
    structure(c(4535000, 4535000, 4536000, 4536000, 4535000, 
    3517000, 3518000, 3518000, 3517000, 3517000), .Dim = c(5L, 
    2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(
    structure(c(4530000, 4530000, 4531000, 4531000, 4530000, 
    3518000, 3519000, 3519000, 3518000, 3518000), .Dim = c(5L, 
    2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(
    structure(c(4531000, 4531000, 4532000, 4532000, 4531000, 
    3518000, 3519000, 3519000, 3518000, 3518000), .Dim = c(5L, 
    2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(
    structure(c(4532000, 4532000, 4533000, 4533000, 4532000, 
    3518000, 3519000, 3519000, 3518000, 3518000), .Dim = c(5L, 
    2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(
    structure(c(4533000, 4533000, 4534000, 4534000, 4533000, 
    3518000, 3519000, 3519000, 3518000, 3518000), .Dim = c(5L, 
    2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(
    structure(c(4534000, 4534000, 4535000, 4535000, 4534000, 
    3518000, 3519000, 3519000, 3518000, 3518000), .Dim = c(5L, 
    2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(
    structure(c(4535000, 4535000, 4536000, 4536000, 4535000, 
    3518000, 3519000, 3519000, 3518000, 3518000), .Dim = c(5L, 
    2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(
    structure(c(4530000, 4530000, 4531000, 4531000, 4530000, 
    3519000, 3520000, 3520000, 3519000, 3519000), .Dim = c(5L, 
    2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(
    structure(c(4531000, 4531000, 4532000, 4532000, 4531000, 
    3519000, 3520000, 3520000, 3519000, 3519000), .Dim = c(5L, 
    2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(
    structure(c(4532000, 4532000, 4533000, 4533000, 4532000, 
    3519000, 3520000, 3520000, 3519000, 3519000), .Dim = c(5L, 
    2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(
    structure(c(4533000, 4533000, 4534000, 4534000, 4533000, 
    3519000, 3520000, 3520000, 3519000, 3519000), .Dim = c(5L, 
    2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(
    structure(c(4534000, 4534000, 4535000, 4535000, 4534000, 
    3519000, 3520000, 3520000, 3519000, 3519000), .Dim = c(5L, 
    2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(
    structure(c(4535000, 4535000, 4536000, 4536000, 4535000, 
    3519000, 3520000, 3520000, 3519000, 3519000), .Dim = c(5L, 
    2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(
    structure(c(4530000, 4530000, 4531000, 4531000, 4530000, 
    3520000, 3521000, 3521000, 3520000, 3520000), .Dim = c(5L, 
    2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(
    structure(c(4531000, 4531000, 4532000, 4532000, 4531000, 
    3520000, 3521000, 3521000, 3520000, 3520000), .Dim = c(5L, 
    2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(
    structure(c(4532000, 4532000, 4533000, 4533000, 4532000, 
    3520000, 3521000, 3521000, 3520000, 3520000), .Dim = c(5L, 
    2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(
    structure(c(4533000, 4533000, 4534000, 4534000, 4533000, 
    3520000, 3521000, 3521000, 3520000, 3520000), .Dim = c(5L, 
    2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(
    structure(c(4534000, 4534000, 4535000, 4535000, 4534000, 
    3520000, 3521000, 3521000, 3520000, 3520000), .Dim = c(5L, 
    2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(
    structure(c(4535000, 4535000, 4536000, 4536000, 4535000, 
    3520000, 3521000, 3521000, 3520000, 3520000), .Dim = c(5L, 
    2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg"))), n_empty = 0L, crs = structure(list(
    epsg = NA_integer_, proj4string = "+proj=laea +lat_0=52 +lon_0=10 +x_0=4321000 +y_0=3210000 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs"), .Names = c("epsg", 
"proj4string"), class = "crs"), class = c("sfc_POLYGON", "sfc"
), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(4530000, 3517000, 4536000, 
3521000), .Names = c("xmin", "ymin", "xmax", "ymax"), class = "bbox"))), .Names = c("Id", 
"total", "geometry"), row.names = c(NA, -24L), class = c("sf", 
"data.frame"), sf_column = "geometry", agr = structure(c(NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_), class = "factor", .Label = c("constant", "aggregate", 
"identity"), .Names = c("Id", "total")))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the approach that [I gave you in an earlier question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/265066/80215) and take account that [`rasterize` doesn't work with sf objects](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/raster/versions/2.6-7/topics/rasterize):

```
polys <- as(polys,'Spatial')

r <- raster(nrows = 4, ncols = 6, xmn = 4530000, xmx = 4536000, ymn = 3517000, ymx = 3521000,
       crs = '+proj=laea +lat_0=52 +lon_0=10 +x_0=4321000 +y_0=3210000 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs')

rr <- rasterize(x = polys, y = r, field = 'total')

plot(rr)
```

[image]

Comment: `rasterize` does work with sf objects, even if not documented...

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have a regular raster, albeit represented as polygons, rasterize is a bit inefficient (not that it matters with the small example data set). Instead, you can do the following.

Create a raster that matches your data:

```
r <- raster(nrow=4, ncol=6, ext=extent(polys), crs="+proj=laea +lat_0=52 +lon_0=10 +x_0=4321000 +y_0=3210000 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m")
```

Extract the centroids of the polygons

```
# with sf: 
xy <- do.call(rbind, st_geometry(st_centroid(polys)))
# with sp
# xy <- coordinates(polys)
```

Match coordinates to cells:

```
i <- cellFromXY(r, xy)
```

Assign cell values

```
r[i] <- polys$Id

# or 

r[i] <- polys$total
```